# How do I get the scroll position of a document?

Tags: jquery, scroll

How to get the scroll position value of a document?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$(document).height() //returns window height

$(document).scrollTop() //returns scroll position from top of document
```

Comment: I was thinkig the same way, but why does

console.log($(this).scrollTop()) = 1187
console.log($(this).height()) = 1762


it differs so much? For 575px if I have scrolled to the bottom of the page.

Where are those 575px gone? Scroll bar can't be 576px :)

Comment: Baaah again my fault. I was looking at scrollbar with opened firebug window.

Ofc it can be 576px now. :)

Thanks i guess topic is closed.

Comment: -1 - That's very nice, but does not answer the question, which was about `scrollHeight`.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: Correct, this is a jquery question. But neither $(document).height() or $(document).scrollTop() gives the desired information. The request was for scrollHeight. The scrollHeight value is the total height available to an element (if it is scrollable, that value may be bigger than it's height). scrollTop returns how far from the top the element would be. Neither answer what the total available height is. See http://help.dottoro.com/ljbixkkn.php for understanding of scrollHeight

Comment: Neither height() or scrollTop() seem to reliably return the value which is obtained from the scrollHeight property.

Comment: This is marked as the answer because it answers the *intended* question of the asker, which was about the height at which the document is currently scrolled... ergo "scrollHeight."  It's a coincidence that this name is used in a different context.

Answer (score 177):

Here's how to get the `scrollHeight` of an element obtained using a jQuery selector:

```
$(selector)[0].scrollHeight
```

If `selector` is the id of the element (e.g. `elemId`), it is guaranteed that the 0-indexed item of the array will be the element you wish to select, and `scrollHeight` will be correct.

Comment: Take care, according to the Mozilla knowledge base, it is not supported from IE versions lesser than the 8.0 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight

Comment: Exactly as @EmanueleDelGrande says: look here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html - for IE < 8 the DOM scrollHeight is implemented but incorrectly. For me it works in IE 6, 7 on netrenderer but might not work in all cases.

Comment: Agreed with @Tomas, use jQuery's abstraction for better handling of cross browser quirks. For example the above can be amended to $(selector).offset().top

Comment: Um, no $(document).offset() returns null, and .offset() has nothing to do with the position of the browser's scroll bars (.offset() returns coordinates of items relative to the document).  

I agree that we should use jQuery when possible, but apparently, as there is no cross browser support for this, jQuery doesn't provide an abstraction for it.

Comment: You can also do
$(selector).get(0).scrollHeight

Comment: Does this use jQuery normalized property or still directs to native browser implementation that may fail?

Comment: @Dmitri Zaitsev
.scrollHeight is a DOM node property, not a jQuery property.

Answer (score 45):

If you are using Jquery 1.6 or above, use prop to access the value.

```
$(document).prop('scrollHeight')
```

Previous versions used to get the value from attr but not post 1.6.

Comment: This returns "undefined" for me with jQuery 1.7.1, as does $(document).attr("scrollHeight").

Comment: That's because it's missing the body element. It needs to be $(document.body).prop('scrollHeight') - at which point you may as well just use document.body.scrollHeight;

Answer (score 6):

```
document.getElementById("elementID").scrollHeight

$("elementID").scrollHeight
```

Comment: so what is the element Id of your document object?  ...perhaps you meant "document.body.scrollHeight"?

Comment: $('#gallery').scrollHeight gives me undefined //#gallery is id of my overflow: auto element, doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

It uses HTML DOM Elements, but not jQuery selector.
It can be used like:

```
var height = document.body.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should solve your problem:

```
$.getDocHeight = function(){
     var D = document;
     return Math.max(Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight,    D.documentElement.scrollHeight), Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight), Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight));
};

alert( $.getDocHeight() );
```

Ps: Call that function every time you need it, the alert is for testing purposes..

Comment: For some reason this function does not work correctly for me; using it inside an iframe. Actual height of <html> is 256px, this function gives me 337px and I have no idea where it's coming from. P.S. I'm using Chrome 18.

Comment: @jurchiks: Do you have a link to where that iframe is, for me to take a look?

Comment: https://www.blade.dateks.lv/salidzinat?ids=58664,43586 . Click on any of the question marks. I've managed to fix the most of it but two of those (and there are more depending on the items being compared) still have some weird, mysterious ~20px margin at the bottom. It disappears when I resize the window though, because I made it change the popup dimensions on window resize.

Answer (score 3):

To get the actual scrollable height of the areas scrolled by the window scrollbar, I used `$('body').prop('scrollHeight')`. This seems to be the simplest working solution, but I haven't checked extensively for compatibility. Emanuele Del Grande notes on another solution that this probably won't work for IE below 8.

Most of the other solutions work fine for scrollable elements, but this works for the whole window. Notably, I had the same issue as Michael for Ankit's solution, namely, that `$(document).prop('scrollHeight')` is returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var scrollHeight = $(scrollable)[0] == document ? document.body.scrollHeight : $(scrollable)[0].scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for example, this code put the scrollbar at the bottom for all DIV tags

Remember: jQuery can accept a function instead the value as argument.
"this" is the object treated by jQuery, the function returns the scrollHeight property of the current DIV "this" and do it for all DIV in the document.

```
$("div").scrollTop(function(){return this.scrollHeight})
```