# $("#someDiv").attr("scrollHeight") not working in jquery-1.6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

`$("#someDiv").attr("scrollHeight")` works in jquery **1.3.2** for all browsers. But on updating to jquery **1.6.1**, it only works in IE9.
Firefox 4.0.1, Google Chrome 11 and  Safari 5 all return undefined.
`$("#someDiv").get(0).scrollHeight` however still works for all browsers.

Anybody knows what is going on?, is **`attr("scrollHeight")`** broken in the newest jquery (i.e version 1.6.1)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, though that is relevant to the answer.

Comment: Indeed. Not every question on the same topic is a duplicate, no matter how bored you may be getting of answering them.

Comment: According to the [comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6921849/684229) the `$("#someDiv").get(0).scrollHeight` will not work in IE <8.0 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight)

Comment: Look here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html - for IE < 8 the DOM scrollHeight is implemented but incorrectly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

jQuery 1.6 introduced `.prop` and changed the meaning of `.attr`.

[Read all about it.](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

<sub>(Always worth checking the documentation first; [the page for `.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) talks about this too.)</sub>

Comment: So `.prop()` now does most of what `.attr()` used to do.

`.attr()` now returns the value as it exists in the markup so in my case I didn't have the scrollHeight attribute set from the markup hence the undefined result. Changing my solution to `$("#someDiv").prop("scrollHeight")` however got the expected results as this retrieved the scrollHeight property from the Dom.

Comment: @adentum: Sounds about right. It's a horrifically massive API change that, whilst well-intentioned and properly grounded in logic, comes far too late IMO.

Comment: @Tomalak It's late, but not too late. Better late than never.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee: With an API, quite often it's better never than late.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, but not this time! As I say, it's late, but not too late.