# Is there any way to find document height till where we scrolled?

Tags: jquery, html, height

I am designing a site, in which i would like to display certain information on every section., ie

```
example.com/#section1
example.com/#section2
example.com/#section3
```

when i click those links, the page scrolls to that section.

After that, in top it should display as 'sectionx' (or something else that i can customize )

by using jquery i can find only document total height and window height.

Help me,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This address your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407133/document-scrollheight

Comment: are you talking about: `window.scrollTop` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your question has already been answered here - This address your question - [How do I get the scroll position of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407133/document-scrollheight)

`$(document).scrollTop()`

Answer (score 0):

Could you use anchor tags and then a top fixed div (or even a div that animates into view on click) with content from a jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```

See the reference here : [Jquery scrollTop](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp)

There's also a HTML DOM way to do so :

```
element.scrollTop
```

See the reference here : [DOM Object ScrollTop](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)