# keep div scrolled to bottom - jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a chatbox thing on a webpage hooked up to a WebSocket. I was just wondering how I keep the chatbox always scolled to the bottom. I have something that kind of works but it breaks too easily. Take a look here: http://sightofnick.com/public/sub-routine(alpha-24)/public.socket.io.html

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

EDIT:
I guess what I'm asking is, what is the best way to keep the scroll pinned to the bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks too easily"? It seems to be working fine...

Comment: At one point or another it will just stop scrolling down. I guess what I'm asking is, is what is the best method to keep the scroll pinned to the bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get the height of `#display` you are probably using `.height()`, and since there is a scrollbar I can assume you are using `overflow: auto`?

If this is the case, then `.height()` will always get the hardcoded value in the CSS, rather than the actual height generated by the content.

In order to fix it use `$('#display')[0].scrollHeight` instead of `$('#display').height()` - this will give you the actual height (in px) according to the current content, no matter how you've set it in the CSS.

[How do I get the real .height() of a overflow: hidden or overflow: scroll div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522579/how-do-i-get-the-real-height-of-a-overflow-hidden-or-overflow-scroll-div)