# How to retrieve the real height of a #div (including overflowed parts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

The same way i use this to detect when user scolled down the whole page:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
    var diff = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - $(document).height();
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()   || (diff < 5 && diff > -5)){
           console.log('yay!');
    }
 });
```

I wanted to do the same inside a dialog,

I am trying like this:

```
$('#dialog').dialog();
$('#dialog').scroll(function(){
     var scroll = $('#dialog').scrollTop();
    var height = $('#dialog ul').outerHeight(true);
    if(scroll == height){
         $('#dialog').css('background','#999');
    }else{
        console.log('scrolltop is '+scroll+' and height is: '+height);
    }
})
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/AgFXz/

The problem i guess is that i am not retrieving the whole #dialog size but the visible (CSS Defined property) size..

How can i know when user scrolled till the end of the dialog's scroll?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please don't tell me that i have to Do it counting the elements...

Comment: Seems to be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522579/how-do-i-get-the-real-height-of-a-overflow-hidden-or-overflow-scroll-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried scrollHeight property?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#dialog ul')[0].scrollHeight` to get the scroll height of the element and then subtract the actual height `$('#dialog ul').outerHeight(true);` to know when the user has scrolled to the bottom.

```
var height = $('#dialog ul')[0].scrollHeight - $('#dialog ul').outerHeight(true);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AgFXz/1/)

This is what the console log says (I click the down arrow each time)

```
scrolltop is 40 and height is: 250
scrolltop is 80 and height is: 250
scrolltop is 120 and height is: 250
scrolltop is 160 and height is: 250
scrolltop is 200 and height is: 250
scrolltop is 240 and height is: 250
```

At the end, both `scroll` and `height` are 250. This doesn't show in the log but if you check it manually you'll see.

```
$('#dialog').scrollTop();
250
```

Comment: The demo is not working, detects height = 0. so the color is changed when user scrolls back to the top again

Comment: This is what happens for me: Scroll around, no change. As soon as the scroll bar hits the bottom, color changes to `#999`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: do you see a different height than 0 in the logs? sure is the right link? thanks (it is what i want, but it's not happening in the DEMO)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone noticed, you should use `scrollHeight`.
But there is another problem in your demo:

```
#dialog ul{
    height:150px;
}
```

And of course `$('#dialog ul').outerHeight(true)` and `$('#dialog ul').innerHeight()` and even `$('#dialog ul')[0].scrollHeight` will equal 150.

You need to check scrollHeight of overflowed element, so use `$('#dialog')[0].scrollHeight`