# Lazy Load and infinitive scrolling issue in jQuery to find new height of an element with position absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element with position absolute and overflow scroll like this:

```
<style>
.sevencov {
    position: absolute;
    width: 61.333%;
    left: 16.667%;
    top: 46px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="sevencov">
  <a id="load-more" class="load-more" title="Load More" onclick="myFunction()"></a>
</div>
```

I want to fire the load more button at a certain % of the div on scroll, using jQuery I tried this:

```
$(function () {
    var prevHeight = $('.sevencov').height();
    $('.sevencov').scroll(function () {
            var curHeight = $(this).height();          
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - curHeight)*44) {
               $('#load-more').click();
            }            

    });
});
```

But the problem is that it fires multiple times because the height of my div `sevencov` is always the same and I'm not able to find a solution, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have given you the working copy of your code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is called as `Lazy Loading`

You can play with `scrollTop`, `innerHeight` and `scrollHeight` as below.

**Documentation**

[scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) - Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for the element

[innerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) - Get the current computed inner height (including padding but not border) for the element

[scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) - The height of an element's content, including content not visible on the screen due to overflow

In the below `snippet`, you can place your `ajax` call.

Also, the below `snippet` had `window.loadProfile = loadProfile;` to make sure your inline `onclick` works with the parameters `onClick="loadProfile(184, '', 'user69')"`. If possible, you can replace this with `jquery click event` like, `$('#load-more').on('click', function(){ /* ajax call */ });`

```js
$(function () { 
  
    var testContent = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. ';
  var increment = 20;
  var contentLoading = false;
  var sevencovDiv = $('.sevencov');
  
  function loadProfile(id, text, user) {
    // You can do a ajax call here instead of a below code
    for(var i = 0; i < increment; i++) {
      sevencovDiv.html(sevencovDiv.html() + testContent);
    }
    
    contentLoading = false; // make this false once the content loaded from ajax call
  }
  
  loadProfile();
  
  window.loadProfile = loadProfile;

    $('.sevencov').scroll(function () {                  
      if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        if(!contentLoading) {
          //loadMore();
          contentLoading = true;
          $('#load-more').click();
        }
    }

    });
});
```

```css
.sevencov {
    position: absolute;
    width: 61.333%;
    left: 16.667%;
    top: 46px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sevencov">
  <a id="load-more" class="load-more" title="Load More" onClick="loadProfile(184, '', 'user69')"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Aruna, but my load more button has this attribute `onClick="loadProfile(184, '', 'user69')"` and it changes every time it loads new ajax data

Comment: it's difficult for me because I create the lazy button in PHP (and I wish to keep things like that)

Comment: @SimonLeCat I have updated the code and explanation of the code. Please have a look.

Comment: @SimonLeCat Great :-)

Comment: just last question...how can I anticipate the fire? I tried `... >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight * 0.9` but again it fires multiple time :S

Comment: @SimonLeCat I have updated the code with a variable `contentLoading` to avoid it firing multiple times and set it as false inside the ajax response once the content received from the server.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2522592/1954933)), to get the height of a overflow element, you should use `$('.sevencov')[0].scrollHeight` instead of `.height()`

Comment: ok thanks, I changed this too `if ($(this).scrollTop() > curHeight * 0.7) {` ...the height is calculated correctly but again the jQuery fires multiple time the load-more button

Comment: eg. it fires when `curHeight=24386` and `scrollTop=2410` it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It fires multiple times because it's inside the scroll callback. If you scroll 100px, the scroll function will be called a lot of times.

Comment: Try the @Aruna answer for the load problem